# Dynamically suffix a "selected" value from another list to previous "selected" list without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, multi-select

[Please see this image before reading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeRhr.png)

The requirement is to dynamically alter a `multi-select` list, and add a suffix to the selected options. These "Suffix Values" are selected options from another individual select lists.

I am saving these selections in my Session Variables, in an ordered manner

```
P94_DYNAMIC_ML ==> "Habib" : "Aiman"

P94_DYNAMIC_SL ==> "FAST 1" : "AL SAFEER 1"
```

Expecting this could be done at client side itself.

**PS:** I work on Databases,`SQL` & `PLSQL` mainly. Had a recent chance to work on Web Development. So very naive in `Javascript` & `jquery`, and unable to write any appropriate code in my HTML. Seeking help here, so that I can get an idea where to at-least begin with. Thereafter, I will do my best

Comment: Try to provide a live example.

Comment: I have provided an visual image Mr.X, could you get an idea through that https://i.stack.imgur.com/WeRhr.png

Comment: This is a help service not a code writing service. Post your own effort and explain what's not working.

Comment: Considering the image, you don't want to alter a select element, you want to add a suffix to a couple of names in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something :

```js
$("#x1-suffix").on("change", function () {
  $("#x1").text("x1 - " + $(this).val());
});
$("#x2-suffix").on("change", function () {
  $("#x2").text("x2 - " + $(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li id="x1">x1</li>
  <li id="x2">x2</li>
</ul>
<div>
  <label for="x1-suffix">x1 suffix : </label>
  <select name="x1_suffix" id="x1-suffix">
    <option value="empty">pick one</option>
    <option value="s1">s1</option>
    <option value="s2">s2</option>
    <option value="s3">s3</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div>
  <label for="x2-suffix">x2 suffix : </label>
  <select name="x2_suffix" id="x2-suffix">
    <option value="empty">pick one</option>
    <option value="s1">s1</option>
    <option value="s2">s2</option>
    <option value="s3">s3</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: I did try, but the problem here is my select lists are in 2 different pages. When i close the modal window, I am catching the values in  variable, which is set in the main page, where select list should be altered. thanks for you effort...

Comment: @AliHabib A modal is usually not a page in itself, I'm not sure to understand.